# Create keyboard shortcut to quit the kernel

Tags: kernel, keyboard

I would like to reset all my user-defined symbols using a keyboard shortcut. I believe the mouse-activated command is Evaluation->Quit Kernel. How can I do this without having to use the mouse?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612 - you can create your own kernel quit keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Linux, Mac, or Windows?

Comment: On Mac, there is way to create shortcuts for any menu item (for any software): https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/how-to-make-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-any-macos-menu-items-and-to-launch-your-favorite-apps/ (gist: System Preferences>Keyboard>Shortcuts>App Shortcuts>"+")